# Naming a Browser Helper Object

Tags: c#, .net, com, bho

I have created a browser helper object in C# and it is working fine. I only have one litte problem and that is when I register the addon and go to Internet Explorer and click managed addons. The window that pops up shows the name of my addon like namespace.class where namespace is the namespace of my project and class is the classname in my project. I have tried setting every possible thing I can think of in the AssemblyInfo.cs but nothing changes the this name.

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My title1")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("My title1")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My title1")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("My title1")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("My title1")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("My title1")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyDefaultAlias("My addon")]
```

This is my currecnt Assembly settings but it doesnt do what I want. I have also read something about using ProgId but im not quite sure where to set this but I think I have tried putting it everywhere by now and it doesnt work.

I have tried putting the ProdId between the namespace and the class but it doesnt seem to do anything. Is this the rigth place to put this?

```
[
ComVisible(true),
Guid("4070B9C7-D748-4A07-920B-63B3533F86F1"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ProgId("My Adon")
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's not interested in the assembly.  It's interested in the class that implements the browser helper object.  Change the ProgId of the class with the `[ProgId("whatever you want")]` attribute.  By default, if you do not define it, the ProgId defaults to "%Namespace%.%Classname%" for whatever your defined namespace and class are.  The ProgId attribute is in System.Runtime.InteropServices.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly solved the problem.

```
    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void Register(Type type)
    {
        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);
        if (registryKey == null)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHOKEYNAME);

        RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);
        if (ourKey == null)
            ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);

        RegistryKey addonNameKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"CLSID\" + guid, true);
        if (addonNameKey == null)
            addonNameKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\" + guid);

        addonNameKey.SetValue("", "ESSO");
        addonNameKey.Close();
        ourKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1);

        registryKey.Close();
        ourKey.Close();
    }
```

With this com registration function and manualy changing the value of the key I named addonNameKey I was able to change the displayed name of the BHO. Since I was also using the visual studio installer I needed to add an installer class to make the BHO register with this name.